# Nprogess.js parent changed but the progress bar not showing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
NProgress.start();
NProgress.configure({
    parent: '#progressbar'
});
```

I have changed the parent to `#progressbar` but the progress bar is not showing. When I delete configuration lines, progress bar displayed top of the page.

Comment: Please provide more code to help the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

Progressbar was hidden because I have not added padding. I added padding to the progress bar and it is displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#progressbar {
 padding:15px;
}
```